# Is it possible to construct a trigonometric series convergent in $(0,1)$ while divergent in $(2,3)$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Here by a trigonometric series, I mean

$$ f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n e^{ i b_n x }, $$

where $a_n$, $b_n$ can be arbitrary complex numbers.

Two Questions:

> **Q1.** Is it possible to make such a function $f$ convergent in $(0,1)$ but divergent in $(2,3)$?
>
> **Q2.** As a related question, is it possible to make $f$ differentiable in $(0,1)$ but not differentiable in $(2,3)$?

Comment: Converges in what sense? Pointwise?

Comment: Yes, pointwise.